# How to subtract multiple datasets with their own determined slopes using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

new to Python here and I'm running into an issue. I have 10+ datasets that have intensity (I) and distance (q) column values. Plotting the I*q^4 vs q^4, I attained a list of the slopes for all of the data sets using:

```
filenames = sorted(glob.glob('sans*.ABS'))

slopelist=[]
for f in filenames:
    filelist.append(f)

for f in filenames:
    q, I = np.genfromtxt(fname=f,skip_header=13, skip_footer=0,unpack=True)
    x=q**4
    y=I*q**4
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x, y)
    slopelist.append(slope)
```

Now, the issue is I have to somehow subtract each dataset's intensity values with their respective slopes. I've only been able to subtract all of the datasets using a single slope, using:

```
IB=I-slopelist[1]
```

Do I have to use some sort of loop? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not do the subtraction in the same for loop?

Comment: I don't know how to incorporate the slope subtraction into the loop. Any ideas?

Comment: are you planning for each dataset to have 3 columns? `I, q and IB`

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the end, I'd like to have a column of q (which is the same in all cases) and the IBs of all the datasets.

Comment: have you tried using `pandas`, it's made for a job like this

Comment: I have never. I've only really dabbled in Python recently so I'm still very much learning the basics.

Comment: can you post the output of `filenames`

Comment: ['sans48538.ABS', 'sans48540.ABS', 'sans48541.ABS', 'sans48542.ABS', 'sans48543.ABS', ......', 'sans48957.ABS', 'sans48983.ABS', 'sans49027.ABS']

Answer (score 0):

Do the calculation and saving in this loop

```
for f in filenames:
    q, I = np.genfromtxt(fname=f,skip_header=13, skip_footer=0,unpack=True)
    x=q**4
    y=I*q**4
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x, y)
    IB = I - slope
    np.savetxt('output_file.txt', (q,Ib))
```

Comment: This seems to only yield a single subtraction

Comment: are you only getting one file output, if so `filenames` might be a list of only one variable

Comment: Yes, I only get one file output. Actually on further inspection, it's trying to subtract the intensity values with the slope values  (i.e. the list of slopes calculated in the data set order, and not the individual slopes specific to each dataset).

Comment: `filenames` should be a list of all files

Comment: Yes it is. But the files have more than 1 variable.